# how to tell autotest to correctly track changes in app source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest, acceptance-testing

I want to get autotest to run Steak acceptance tests whenever one of my rails app's relevant files is changed. After studying Rspec's and Cucumber's own autotest configs, I'm trying the following mappings:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  at.add_mapping(%r%^spec/acceptance/.*_spec.rb$%, true) { |filename, _|
    filename
  }
```

at.add_mapping(%r%^app/(models|controllers|helpers|lib)/.*rb$%) { 
    at.files_matching %r%^spec/acceptance/.*_spec.rb$%
  }

at.add_mapping(%r%^app/views/(.*)/.*rb$%) { 
    at.files_matching %r%^spec/acceptance/.*_spec.rb$%
  }
end

the first one works: whenever a Steak spec is changed, it gets run again.

but the second and third don't. changing any source files under the /app subdirectories just gets ignored.

what's the correct way to get these mappings to work?

thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just changed my `.autotest` file to add:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  at.add_mapping(%r%^spec/acceptance/.*_spec.rb$%, true) { |filename, _|
    filename
  }

  at.add_mapping(%r%^app/(models|controllers|helpers|lib)/.*rb$%, true) {
    at.files_matching %r%^spec/acceptance/.*_spec.rb$%
  }

  at.add_mapping(%r%^app/views/(.*)$%, true) {
    at.files_matching %r%^spec/acceptance/.*_spec.rb$%
  }
end
```

And this is working but I don't know the collateral effects of invoking acceptance tests before others (the `true` flag on `add_mapping`)

Comment: Hey Gabriel, thanks your response and sorry for my (huge) delay in getting back. I couldn't test this as the project was dropped, but it's worth mentioning that, afterwards, I found that making it work like it does with Cucumber is just way more involved than I originally imagined.

Comment: From the votes up it looks like it's working for other people, so I'm marking it as correct. valeu Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

For RSpec 1.3:

I had to use the :post_initialize hook because the built-in RSpec support starts by clearing all existing mappings. So it was clearing these out and then adding the default RSpec mappings. But using the :post_initialize hook (instead of :initialize on the first line) fixed it.

I also had to put all this in autotest/discover.rb instead of .autotest.